# iOS psd to xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, psd

I am creating an iOS app and I have designed an interface using photoshop. The PSD image size is that of iPhone 4s and the storyboard I am designing for is also that of iPhone 4s. I was expecting that I could just slice an image from my PSD, save it, and it would import into my storyboard the correct size. However, this is not the case. It appears that the image is appearing in storyboard double the size of what it should be.  The image has been imported into a new image set, onto category iPhone -> 2x and the image name is logo@2x.png

I was wondering where I was going wrong, and why the size of the image in the storyboard does not correlate to that of the image in the PSD

TLDR;

> PSD designed to iPhone 4S dimensions,
>
> Size of img in XCode isn't what I expect, the size is almost double size

http://screencast.com/t/2GcmSjQSYpjs - PSD
http://screencast.com/t/IicMsdepl3q - Storyboard (note width + height is the same w/h that is in the PSD)

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with iPhone 4, iPhones are shipped with Retina Display, which is a display where pixels density is doubled. So when you want to import an UI graphic element to your project (e.g. an image), you have to make sure it is at least twice the size of the image view container you defined in your storyboard. The file name of these elements should have a `@2x` postfix before the file extension.

Let's make an example: you want a square image file `foo.png` of size 512 × 512 in your view controller. Then you have to provide a file of that image named `foo@2x.png` where its size is doubled, i.e. 1024 × 1024.